# Casting issues in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column name Capacity_Band3 with the value as follows 
'0.8617 x SOQ ^ -0.2155' which is a string.
I am trying to extract the first and last bit in this example 0.8617 by using

```
 cast(substring(Capacity_Band3,1,7) as numeric))
```

but the conversion fails

I am trying to cast it as a numeric value so i can do calculation, what am I doing wrong?

I would also need to do this with the last bit

```
cast(substring(Capacity_Band3,16,22)as numeric))
```

Thank you

Comment: The error is "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

Comment: Check your data, this runs OK  `select cast(N'0.8617 ' as numeric(6,4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE LEFT and Right Function to extract number

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName,6),RIGHT(ColumnName,6)
```

THEN Apply Cast Operation

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(ColumnName,6) AS DECIMAL(18,2)),CAST(RIGHT(ColumnName,6) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with the below code.. you have to mention the precision.

```
    DECLARE @a nvarchar(50)='0.8617 x SOQ ^ -0.2155' 

    SELECT cast(substring(@a,1,7) as decimal(15,4)),cast(substring(@a,16,22) as decimal(15,4))
```

OR

```
   SELECT cast(substring(@a,1,7) as numeric(15,4)),cast(substring(@a,16,22) as numeric(15,4))
```

And if you want to check ,whether the column returns a numeric value, debug
with the following code.

```
SELECT Capacity_Band3
FROM YourTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(substring(Capacity_Band3,1,7)) !=1 
       OR ISNUMERIC(substring(Capacity_Band3,16,22))!=1
```

Comment: Mmm..still getting same error 'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric', I have used cast before but can't understand why its getting these issues

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your text have no special/additional symbols? Take a look at this query:

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(100) = '0.8617 x SOQ ^ -0.2155'

SELECT
    cast(substring(@s,1,7) as numeric(19,4)),
    cast(substring(@s,16,22)as numeric(19,4))
```

Precision is required but won't produce errors. If it is part of bigger query make sure all records have this format. Try wrapping source string with `LTRIM/RTRIM`, trim `SUBSTRING` result as well.

For debugging purposes you can use:

```
SELECT
    substring(Capacity_Band3,1,7),
    substring(Capacity_Band3,16,22)
FROM YourTable
```

Make sure all records are valid numbers.

Comment: This worked, but how would i make it work without the variable, there are no special symbols I don't think. What you see there is what the value is?

Answer (score 1):

You got the parameters for the substring wrong. Also, a numeric without precision is same as an int.

```
 declare @Capacity_Band3 varchar(30) = '0.8617 x SOQ ^ -0.2155' 

 select cast(substring(@Capacity_Band3,1,7) as numeric(10,4)),
 cast(substring(@Capacity_Band3,16,8)as numeric(10,4))
```